# Simple jQuery Each Function

Tags: jquery, function, each, gsap

I have a codePen that has a simple setup. I am trying to get the appropriate button to click to reveal the appropriate image. We have a 'red box' that should reveal only the 1st image, and a 'green box' that should reveal only the 2nd image.

I know I can do this with simple javascript clicks--but I will have a lot of boxes on the page, and I want to do some sort of an each loop that will know which square I clicked on to reveal the right image associated with that square.

How can I set this up properly, so that I can have one click function that knows which square I've clicked to reveal the correct image ? I added some 'data' attributes to each image, thinking maybe I can reference that somehow with an each function...I'm just not exactly sure how to do that!

[Here's the codePen to see what I mean](http://codepen.io/celli/pen/OyGrEB)

```
//reveal the appropriate large image here with javascript.
//Maybe I can use an array to choose the correct image?
//But how will the click function know which one to reveal ?
//Maybe an 'each' function can help,
//but I'm not sure how to set that up properly...

var correctImage = ["#img1", "#img2"];

$(".box").click(function( event ) {
  var largeImages = new TimelineMax();
  largeImages.set(correctImage, {css:{display: "block"}})
        .from(correctImage, 1, {autoAlpha:0, ease:Sine.easeOut});

});

// just a reset button here
$(".reset").click(function( event ) {
  var largeImages2 = new TimelineMax();
  largeImages2.set(correctImage, {clearProps: "all"});

});
```

Comment: It could be much simpler i.e. you don't really need to add `data-**` attributes to your elements, nor do you need unique IDs to identify them: **[jsFiddle](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/GpLVMx)** using the **[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** method of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather simple. I will add an example of html below with javascript to demonstrate how to know which button was clicked.

```
.my_image {
    display: none;
}

<a class="my_button" data-id="1">Test button 1</a>
<a class="my_button" data-id="2">Test button 2</a>
<a class="my_button" data-id="3">Test button 3</a>

<img class="my_image" data-id="1" src="http://blog.jelanieshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/girl-laughing.jpg" />
<img class="my_image" data-id="2" src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/laughing-girl-1938830.jpg" />
<img class="my_image" data-id="3" src="http://dailyplateofcrazy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Beautiful-Girl-Laughing.jpg" />
```

The magic:

```
$(".my_button").click(function(){
    $(".my_image[data-id="+$(this).attr("data-id")+"]").show();
});
```

I hope this answers your question or at least helps you.

Comment: actually, one question: where are we getting the 'this' from ? I am trying this in my project and I can't seem to get it to work--only when I replace the 'this' can I actually get it to work...so I know everything else is working, but it's just not translating what 'this' is ?

Comment: This is the current object you are working with within the scope of your function. So lets say I click on an element, the element is passed as this to the click event. Lets say you do a $.post("something", {something}, function(){as soon as you get here the this will be different}). So one way you can keep a hold of this is to assign it to a variable. So you can add var myElement = $(this); at the begining of the function, so you can keep track of your element. So now if you want to reference the element again you can simply use myElement.show(); or whatever you want to use it for. :)